# DeepLinking React Native App with firebase deeplink

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

i'm trying to implement deeplink functionality in react native app using firebase deeplink, functionality is similar like sharing functionality of flipkart and amazon app, when we share a product to social media it should redirect to product specific page

i have implemented **npm i react-native-share** for sharing link with some description and images

code snippet for sharing

```
       url: "https://stepout.page.link/activity_id/?id=" + this.state.activityType_id,
       title: this.state.activityTypeName,
       message: "Test Data",
       subject: "Share Link", //  for email
       social: Share.Social.FACEBOOK})
              .then(result => console.log("Share Insta=>", result))
              .catch(errorMsg => console.log("Error Share Insta=>", errorMsg))
}}
```

after sharing link to insta when i user clicks on it it will give popup which displays browser and myApp

when i clicked on myApp then i'm getting **null**

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
         Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
             console.log('initial url:' + url)
         })
```

but when i tried with branch i'm getting some value only issue is i have to click on app only, if i'm comming from browser it shows **www.google.com**

```
branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Error from Branch: ' + error)
                return
            }

kindly help how to handle dynamic link when its clicked from other app, And guide me is there any issue while generating dynamic link
            console.log("Params-->", params);
        })
```